# meaning of 'shift' for 'relocate'

Tags: vocabulary

When people move places from one apartment to another one they can say 'we moved' or 'we relocated'. Is it also valid to say 'we shifted'?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shift

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shift

These definitions do not provide such an example.

Comment: You could, and people might understand, but it would sound weird. Do you have an example sentence where you want to use it? Did you hear someone use it (please give a quote and link). Or are you just wondering?

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be a cultural thing.
In the US, I know its common to say 'we moved'.

Though in India, people do say we shifted rather than we moved. Its kind of like flats vs apartments.

You might find the below answer helpful: [Which is correct: I'll be moving next month or I'll be shifting next month?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144552/which-is-correct-ill-be-moving-next-month-or-ill-be-shifting-next-month)

Comment: Not only might that be useful: it's a duplicate question, in that the answer(s) [and comments] answer this question.  Yes, *shift* can be used like that, but only in India.